# Pivoting data with date as a row in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have data that I've left in a format that will allow me to pivot on dates that look like:

```
Region                    0              1              2             3
Date                      2005-01-01     2005-02-01     2005-03-01    ....
East South Central        400            500            600
Pacific                   100            200            150
.
.
Mountain                  500            600            450
```

I need to pivot this table so it looks like:

```
0     Date           Region                     value
1     2005-01-01     East South Central         400 
2     2005-02-01     East South Central         500  
3     2005-03-01     East South Central         600  
.
.   
4     2005-03-01     Pacific                    100 
4     2005-03-01     Pacific                    200
4     2005-03-01     Pacific                    150
.
.
```

Since both `Date` and `Region` are under one another I'm not sure how to `melt` or `pivot` around these strings so that I can get my desired output.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the solution you are looking for. Shown by example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
N=100
regions = list('abcdef')
df = pd.DataFrame([[i for i in range(N)], ['2016-{}'.format(i) for i in range(N)], 
                  list(np.random.randint(0,500, N)), list(np.random.randint(0,500, N)), 
                   list(np.random.randint(0,500, N)), list(np.random.randint(0,500, N))])
df.index = ['Region', 'Date', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print(df)
```

This gives

```
            0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7   \
Region       0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7   
Date    2016-0  2016-1  2016-2  2016-3  2016-4  2016-5  2016-6  2016-7   
a           96     432     181      64      87     355     339     314   
b          360      23     162      98     450      78     114     109   
c          143     375     420     493     321     277     208     317   
d          371     144     207     108     163      67     465     130
```

**And the solution to pivot this into the form you want is**

```
df.transpose().melt(id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

which gives

```
        Date variable value
0     2016-0        a    96
1     2016-1        a   432
2     2016-2        a   181
3     2016-3        a    64
4     2016-4        a    87
5     2016-5        a   355
6     2016-6        a   339
7     2016-7        a   314
8     2016-8        a   111
9     2016-9        a   121
10   2016-10        a   124
11   2016-11        a   383
12   2016-12        a   424
13   2016-13        a   453
...
393  2016-93        d   176
394  2016-94        d   277
395  2016-95        d   256
396  2016-96        d   174
397  2016-97        d   349
398  2016-98        d   414
399  2016-99        d   132
```

Comment: Obviously you will need to replace ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  in the melt transform with a list of your regions, but you could get this list by using `list(df.index)[2:]`. Indexing from 2 to skip past the `date` and `Region` rows.